# cpp Sockets between Windows and Linux error

Tags: c++, linux, windows, sockets

I'm coding a crossplatform library and know I've implemented sockets. Here are the files that I wrote:

https://github.com/Bardo91/BOVIL/tree/core_sockets_MergingSOsockets/source/core/comm

Everything seem to work fine if I work in the same OS, I mean, I test the sockets on local machine in Windows (127.0.0.1 through 2048 port) and it was success. Afterwars I test it on local machine in Ubuntu 12.04 and it was fine. Then I tried creating a server on my PC in ubuntu 12.04 and executing the client in an Odroid u3 (arm micro) and It also works. But finally when I tested the library with the server on my PC in Windows and try the connection with the client on the Odroid u3 the connection failed.

To be more precise, connect function (Part of the socket API) returns -1, line 79 in ClientSocket:

```
int iResult = connect( mSocketOut, mPtr->ai_addr, (int) mPtr->ai_addrlen);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    closeSocket();
    mSocketOut = INVALID_SOCKET;
    continue;
}
```

... After that the socket is set to INVALID_SOCKET and then the connection can be made.

Server side:

```
mSocketOut = accept(mSocketOwn, NULL, NULL);
if (mSocketOut == INVALID_SOCKET) {
std::cout << "Accept failed. Error was: " << getLastError() << std::endl;
closeSocket();              
return 1;
}
```

I'm not sure what is going on... Can anyone helps me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry but we're not going to look through all of the source code to debug this for you. Please reduce it to a small example showing the _relevant_ code.

Comment: Check out http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately. Did you check the `errno` when `connect()` failed, what is the error?

Comment: mmmm, ok srry, that wasnt my intention, I thought that the error could be clear with the description

Comment: Oh, I didnt know that connect put the error on errno. I'm going to check it know. Thks

Comment: The first thing I do in determining if a socket error is a failure of the client code vs. the server code is to do a simple "telnet" test. From the command line of the client, type "telnet server 999" , where server is the hostname of the server and 999 is the listening port on that server.  If it connects from the command line, I know the server is ok and it must be a client code problem. If I can't get basic telnet to connect to the port on the server, then it's likely a server code bug.

Comment: I put some code to get the error and it was 111 or connection refused. Afterwards "telnet 192.168.0.109 2048" Says the same. So as Selbie wrote. The error should be at the server. But... Why it only fail when connecting between windows and linux and not with windows-windows or linux-linux connection?

Comment: Is there any posibility that the error is related with the little-endian and big-endian format? I read something about it while implementing the sockets but I'm not sure about how it exactly affect to the code